# Proper syntax highlighting for compile errors / output?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

Posts often include compiler errors, e.g., from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222002/error-list-is-not-a-template-type)

```cc
In file included from A.cpp:2:
List.h:20: error: ‘List’ is not a template type
A.cpp: In member function ‘void A::NowyObiekt(int)’:
A.cpp:6: error: ‘list_a’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [A.o] Error 1
```

In this case I've explicitly added a `<!-- language: lang-cc -->`, because the question is tagged as C++ which forces the above highlighting.

It looks a bit funny to me, though. How *should* this be highlighted?

Comment: As long as it's **readable**, highlight it any way you want. I often add the CSS highlight comment when someone uses an ID selector or color code and it greys out the entire line. That light grey text is harder to read. You can also specify `none` (or similar) to make it *not* highlight at all.

Comment: I don't think it should be syntax highlighted at all. Compiler output is generally pretty unstructured and even *if* there is structure, it's definitely per-compiler, so you usually can't even decide based on the language tags.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @JoachimSauer, also because I only ever read it on my terminal.

Comment: @Joachim: I'd be inclined to upvote if you (re-)posted that as an answer, sir.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Joachim Sauer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129712/proper-syntax-highlighting-for-compile-errors-output#comment355205_129712):

> I don't think it should be syntax highlighted at all. Compiler output is generally pretty unstructured and even *if* there is structure, it's definitely per-compiler, so you usually can't even decide based on the language tags.